# How to query custom post type by term?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, get-posts

This seems trivial but I can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'     => -1,
            'eventcategory'   => 'nice-events',
            'post_type'       => 'event',
            'post_status'     => 'publish' 
        );

        var_dump(get_posts($args));
```

As you can see, my taxonomy is `eventcategory` and the term is `nice-events`. There are actually over 50 terms and regardless of what term I use in place of `nice-events` I always get the same result: all of the posts. So the term is being ignored and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot make up your own arguments - rather than replacing the `'category'` argument with your taxonomy name, use `'tax_query'`.

See ["taxonomy parameters" section of the codex on get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'eventcategory',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'nice-events',
        ),
    ),
);


$your_query = get_posts( $args );

// do something with $your_query
```

Alternatively, you could make use of the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'eventcategory',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'nice-events'
        ),
    ),
);


$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// do something with $your_query
```

Comment: @kaiser Indeed, you can. I was under the impression `get_posts()` did not support tax_queries. You're right, codex says it does.

Comment: I am not getting any result using your code..

Comment: @jilseego There was a misplaced comma in it - the snippet should now be ready for copy & paste...

Comment: Yah, I corrected that already before you did. Didn't get any result, really.

Comment: The first one gets empty array. The second one returns this: http://pastebin.com/wnGE88Cn, which I don't think it's correct(?).

Comment: So using WP_Query() still gets empty result because `$your_query->have_posts()` returns a boolean `false`.